# MATLAB 2D Streamlines and USA Map Coordinates

Tags: matlab, dictionary, stream

I'm trying to plot streamlines of u and v wind speed components and latitude and longitude 2-d arrays overlaid on an outline of a USA map with geoshow (hence the USA outlat and outlon lat/lon coordinates).  My data looks like this with 4 variables: outlat, outlon, u and v are all 5 X 5 arrays to make it easy.  Despite all the examples i've seen online I do not understand how the outlat and outlon values relate to the startx or X and starty or Y starting points.  My 4 variable data looks like this:

```
 outlat =    
    17.4154   17.4862   17.5570   17.6278   17.6986
    17.4406   17.5114   17.5822   17.6530   17.7239
    17.4657   17.5365   17.6074   17.6783   17.7492
    17.4908   17.5616   17.6325   17.7034   17.7744
    17.5157   17.5866   17.6576   17.7285   17.7995
    outlon = 
    -126.6557 -126.6822 -126.7086 -126.7352 -126.7617
    -126.5816 -126.6079 -126.6344 -126.6608 -126.6874
    -126.5074 -126.5337 -126.5600 -126.5865 -126.6129
    -126.4331 -126.4594 -126.4857 -126.5120 -126.5384
    -126.3588 -126.3850 -126.4113 -126.4375 -126.4639
    u = 
    4.3284    4.2194    4.1311    4.1058    4.1257
    4.2915    4.1725    4.1192    4.0914    4.1078
    4.2893    4.1729    4.0948    3.9822    3.9411
    4.3015    4.1781    4.0060    3.5111    3.2246
    4.3201    4.1979    3.9442    2.6250    2.0477
    v = 
    7.6193    7.5646    7.5514    7.5293    7.4777
    7.5880    7.5226    7.4864    7.4412    7.3617
    7.5464    7.5055    7.4640    7.3788    7.1708
    7.4983    7.4718    7.4614    7.4554    6.9534
    7.4479    7.4317    7.4620    7.8292    7.6354
```

After trying lots of different attempts, I've tried this now and keep getting a BLANK figure with a USA states map and no streamlines with this MATLAB code using meshgrid as follows:

```
figure

ax = usamap('conus');
set(ax, 'Visible','off');  setm(ax,'mapprojection','lambert');
states = shaperead('usastatelo','UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox',...         [dlonlim', dlatlim']);
geoshow(states, 'FaceColor', [1 1 1],'facealpha',0); 
hold on;
x = linspace(0,10,5); y = linspace(0,10,5);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
streamline(outlat,outlon,u,v,X,Y);
```

Do I need to use stream2 to help calculate the streamline? I've tried quiver and got results but I need a streamline plot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "but I need a streamline plot". Have you tried `stremline` or `stream`? what do you mean "do I need to use"? I assume so

Comment: Hi - i've tried streamline as you can see in my code above and I've tried stream2 but all with blank maps.

Comment: x = linspace(0,10,5); y = linspace(0,10,5);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
streamline(outlat,outlon,u,v,X,Y);

Comment: Hi - i'm completely happy if I can just get the streamline portion of the code above to work and I can figure out the rest.  It is the X and Y values or the startx and starty values that I'm not understanding how relates to the outlat and outlon or latitude and longitude arrays.  Thank you!!